# Lower triangular matrix-vector product

Tags: fortran, matrix-multiplication

For a programming exercise, I was given the lower triangular elements of a symmetric 3x3 matrix saved as an array

```
|1 * *|

|2 4 *| => [1,2,3,4,5,6]

|3 5 6|
```

I need to make the product C(i)=C(i)+M(i,j)V(j) where M is the symmetric matrix and V is a vector.

```
V =>[A,B,C]
C(1)=1*A + 2*B + 3*C
C(2)=2*A + 4*B + 5*C
C(3)=3*A + 5*B + 6*C
```

I am trying to make an efficient algorithm  that can perform this product

I can easily generate all the product I need for C(3) However, I have a problem when I try to generate the values C(1), C(2) and I don't know how to get around this without using extra memory.

This is what I have done

```
k=6
n=3

  DO 1 j = n,1,-1
    l= k
    DO 2 i = n,j + 1,-1
       C(i) = C(i) + V(j)*M(l)
       l = l - 1           
2   enddo             
    C(j) = V(j)*M(k-n+j)
    k = k - (n-j+1)
1 enddo
```

The problem I have is that I can no generate and add the 2*B for C(1) and the 5*C for C(2). The goal of the exercise is to use as few steps and as little array space as possible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest you remove the (archaic) loop numbers from both the `do` and `enddo` statements.  As used above, they are entirely redundant.  If you ever find yourself needing to identify loop beginnings and endings the modern way is to name the statements.

Comment: Please show a complete program, it makes it so much easier to work out what you are doing if there is a complete, compilable code to look at and work with. And could you clarify "as fewer steps and array spaces as possible", do you mean as few operations and as little memory as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code:

- In the outer loop, you assign `C(n)` (probably the diagonal entries), so the computation of inner loop is not used at all
- You are looping over the lower left triangle from back to front, if you would reverse that, the indexing inside the vectorized matrix would be much simpler
- The calculation of the position inside the matrix (`k` and `l`) is wrong
- You do not calculate the products of the mirrored elements

Here is my solution that honors above points:

```
  ! Loop over all elements in the lower left triangle
  k = 0
  do j=1,n
    ! Increment the position inside the unrolled matrix
    k = k+1
    ! diagonal entries, i = j
    c(j) = c(j) + v(j)*M(k)

    ! off-diagonal entries
    do i=j+1,n
      ! Increment the position inside the unrolled matrix
      k = k+1
      ! Original entry
      c(i) = c(i) + v(j)*M(k)
      ! Mirrored one
      c(j) = c(j) + v(i)*M(k)
    enddo !i
  enddo !j
```

Comment: For the first loop, you start with i =0?  for c(i) = c(i) + v(i)*M(k) and n is still equal to 3 right?

Comment: Sorry, typo. Should be `j` not `i`. Fixed. Originally, I had `i=j` set explicitly. Then I decided to pull this into the comment

Comment: Really Nice!! with that correction the after the looping the elements of the C array are correct.

Comment: Do you think this algorithm can be used for a matrix of any n size or need to be generalized?

Comment: @user3671704 If it is following the same scheme, then yes - it is a generic implementation.

Comment: Is there any well-developed solution/function in Fortran that reverts vectorized covariance (lower triangular part as in this example) to covariance/does the multiplication without the loop or in very efficient/fast way?