# Efficiently revert back to covariance matrix from lower triangular vectorized version -OR- do matrix-vector multiplication in Fortran

Tags: fortran, vectorization, matrix-multiplication, vector-multiplication

My question is very much related to the question asked here:
[Lower triangular matrix-vector product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45093764/lower-triangular-matrix-vector-product#)

so the example also is a good/relevant example for my question too.

I try to compute matrix-vector product, where I have a vectorized covariance (storing only lower triangular part).

The loop solution seems to be overly slow in Fortran when I need to compute it many times. Is there any good/fast way to do it perhaps avoiding the loop?

Comment: I'd first look at an optimised, threaded version of dtpmv (see https://www.math.utah.edu/software/lapack/lapack-blas/dtpmv.html) such as that in MKL. If that's not fast enough you'll probably either have to look at distributed memory parallelism, or an entirely different algorithm

Comment: thanks, looks exactly what I needed...

Comment: The correct solution was to use dspmv. dtpmv assumes A is lower/upper triangular stored in a compact form, while dspmv assume A is symmetric stored in a compact form using lower/upper triangular parts of it.